# What equipment do I need for the Alcoholism Program?

Tags: prison-architect

I want to start the alcoholism program for my prisoners, but as you can see in the screenshot below it is flashing "NO EQUIPMENT". However, as far as I can tell I have everything I need. I have a psychiatrist, a common room and lots of chairs. What else do I need? (If the image is too small open it in a new tab, the full resolution is 1920x1080).

[image]

Comment: Do you have any alcoholics?

Comment: @Lawton It says "3 in queue" so I presume so

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feedback for programs that encounter problems isn't very helpful.  It can be any number of problems:

- Psychologist can't reach the room (although this should come up as "NO TEACHER")
- The room isn't zoned for use by prisoners, or can't be reached because of other zone restrictions
- Not enough chairs (it may be looking for as many chairs as there are slots, I never tried it without filling the room to program capacity)
- There's not enough "Work" regime to properly fit the program into that portion of the daily schedule
- It's just plain bugging out due to not seeing one or all of the above and needs to reevaluate what you have (opening up the "reschedule" box and manually picking out a timeslot may help)

If it still doesn't work, it may help to review or submit a bug report on the developer's site.

Comment: As far as I can tell points 1-4 are satisfied so I guess it must be a bug. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

Looking at my save games I think the issue may be with the *type* of chairs you are using.  In my common rooms the alcoholics get nice comfy chairs (labelled in games as [Sofa](http://prison-architect.wikia.com/wiki/Sofa)).

[image: View of common room showing 8 'sofas' and 8 slots in the programs window]

As you can see above there are 8 comfy chairs and 8 slots in the programs window (despite the addition of three standard [chairs](http://prison-architect.wikia.com/wiki/Chair) in the room).

When the session runs, the prisoners sit in the comfortable chairs:

[image: Prisoners sitting in the common room for alcoholics group therapy]

Interestingly my experience contradicts that of the wiki articles - it may be worth trying yourself, however.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just needed a minimum amount of chairs (I think 8, could also be 6, but I haven't tried it). And I used the common chairs, not the "comfortable" ones.